# How to add lang attribute to DataTables.js search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using a jQuery plugin that needs to add attribute to all inputs in a page.

`$("input").attr('lang', 'fa');`

I have no problem for adding this to all inputs except for DataTables search box that this code doesn't affect.

I also tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table =   $('#OrdersTable').dataTable();
    $('.dataTables_filter input').attr('lang','fa');
    $("input").attr('lang', 'fa');
});
```

**Edit:**
I tried many things but the problem still exists. To see the problem look at [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/6La4rvx4/) and type numbers in search box and the input box at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

DataTables uses `<input type="search">` for the search box. For some reason applying `lang` attribute doesn't have any effect on that input type.

> **SOLUTION**

Changing input type to `<input type="text">` fixes the issue.

```
$('#example').DataTable();
$('.dataTables_filter input').attr({'lang': 'fa', 'type': 'text'});
```

> **DEMO**

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6La4rvx4/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: no , it doesn't work . please look at my question edit.